# IONIC : Need to set a side-menu to Right side of the application header

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I got two menu on the header menu. A left side "Burger Menu" and a right side menu with "add" symbol. The html content for the two menu are included in a seperate side-menu.html [not on app.html] 
id for the left menu is "menuLeft" and the id for right menu as "menuRight"

The Burger menu appears on the main page and upon proceeding to a child menu , its replaced with a BACK button. This is expected and I am happy with that.

The Right menu is not enabled in any of the pages. I included the below code on only one of the child menu html file where the right menu needs to be appear.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{name}}</ion-title>
    <button ion-button end>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
</ion-navbar>
```

In its corresponding *.ts file I enabled the right menu in the ionViewWillEnter

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'menuRight');
  }
```

Now, I have two issues. 
1. When I include menuToggle in the button tag, the menu disappears. But I want the menu to appear and I should have the menu Toggle feature

2. I am able to make the right menu appear only when menuToggle attribute not mentioned.And still, it is not appearing on the right end of the header, it appears just prior to the Title. Refer screenshot attached.
3. Not sure why I am getting the background for the "add" button. Can I make it transparent?

[image]

Kindly let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your navbar to make the menu appears on the right side, and i need more information about to awnser the other questions. Where are you placing the menuToggle ?

```
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>{{name}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons right>
    <button ion-button>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo your suggestion fixed issues 1 and 3, with a minor tweak. Instead of just "right", I have to use "right end to move it to the extreme right of the header. I tried placing the menutoggle in the newly added line. <ion-buttons menuToggle right end>.    and also tried it in the   <button ion-button menuToggle> But if that is included in the html, it hides the add button.

Comment: A simple css tweak "display:block !important" fixed the issue as well.